# PL/SQL - I want to test if a character string contains 1 or more lower-case letters

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using PL/SQL (Oracle 11gR2) I want an IF statement that tests if a string contains 1 or more lower-case letters.

PL/SQL **pseudo-code**:

```
declare
v_string varchar2(100) := 'John';

begin
if v_string contain lower-case letter then
  ... do this
else
  ... do something else
end if;
end;
```

/

Comment: declare
  name varchar2(200) := 'John';
begin
  if regexp_like(name,'[:lower:]') then
    dbms_output.put_line('lowercase');
  else
     dbms_output.put_line('uppercase');
  end if;
end;
/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question but accidentally put it in 'comments'.  Here it is:

```
declare
   name varchar2(200) := 'John';
begin
 if regexp_like(name,'[:lower:]') then
   dbms_output.put_line('lowercase');
 else
    dbms_output.put_line('uppercase');
 end if;
end;
```

/

Comment: You need another set of square brackets to show you're matching a character class: `if regexp_like(v_name,'[[:lower:]]') then`. At the moment you're getting true because the string contains `o`, not because it contains any lower-case character.

Answer (score 2):

Test whether:

```
v_string != upper(string)
```

or not.

Lookout for nulls.

```
coalesce(v_string,'X') != coalesce(upper(string),'X')
```

Comment: The string `123#$#` is equal to `upper('123#$#')` but does not contain a lower-case letter.

Comment: I did reverse the sense of my answer immediately after first posting it, which might have led to confusion. I'm still confused by it. Going to bed now -- let me know in the morning what it was I meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
   v_name varchar2(200) := 'JOHn';
begin
 if regexp_like(v_name,'[:lower:]') then
   dbms_output.put_line('first test lowercase');
 else
    dbms_output.put_line('first test uppercase');
 end if;

 IF v_name != UPPER(v_name) THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('second test lowercase');


 ELSE
 dbms_output.put_line('second test uppercase');
 END IF;
end;
```

test it ... 
output

first test uppercase

second test lowercase

David Aldridge is correct....

Comment: The `regexp_like` test would work if you added another set of square brackets to show you're matching a character class: `if regexp_like(v_name,'[[:lower:]]') then`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(v_string != upper(string) AND regexp_count(string,'[[:alpha:]]' > 0 )
then
   -- Has Lower case
end if
```

It also checks, if the string contains any alphabets!